# How can I share an app I created for 2sxc

Tags: 2sxc

I created a weather widget with 2sxc and I want to share the app.
How can I share this app with the community?

It is made to load data from the OpenWeatherMap API?

Answer (score 0):

Go into administration menu, App tab, and "Export this entire App".
Will create a zip for download.
Just share it or place it in a git account.

Comment: This is the right answer. If you think it's good enough to list on the 2sxc.org/apps section, contact us there.